# How to describe a statistical dataset more precisely?

Tags: probability, statistics, data-analysis

I am a newbie in stat and I need to be able to do this for a GIS application:

Say I have the following dataset of only two possible values $0$ and $1$:

$0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1$

The mean would equal $\frac{4}{8}=0.5$

Thus to find out how many $1$'s were in the intial dataset, we would simply multiply the mean by the total number of values and get $4$.

Now consider a dataset with $\it three$ distinct values, $0,0.5$ and $1$

$0,0.5,0.5,1,1,1,0,0$

The mean would again equal $\frac{4}{8}=0.5$. In this case, would there be a way of determining how many values of $0.5$ and how many values of $1$ were in the dataset? Perhaps using the standard deviation, sum, median, or range?

Comment: it looks like you want to compress data, but what summary statistics are you allowing? Your suggested statistics (mean, total # of observations, and sd) is not enough to recover the counts: you get 3 unkowns with 2 equations.

Comment: The software allows the following summary stats: Mean, Median,Range, Standard Deviation and Sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good way to store data, but if you are absolutely certain that data can only take the values $0, \frac12, 1$ then it is usually possible to recover the numbers of each from *Mean*, *Standard Deviation* and *Sum*, and you may be able to something similar with any three possible values.  Let's call $m=\text{Mean}$, $d=\text{Standard Deviation}$ and $s=\text{Sum}$.

First, deal with the case where $m=0$ is zero (the others will be zero too).  Then all the individual values are $0$ too, though you do not know how many there are.

Otherwise you can find the number of values with $n=\frac{s}{m}$.

Next you need to know whether your standard deviation calculation involves division by $n$ or by $n-1$, so in your example of $0,0.5,0.5,1,1,1,0,0$ does it give about $0.4330127$ or about $0.462910$? If the latter, you may have an issue when $n=1$ but then the only value is $m$. In what follows, I will assume the latter, but if not then replace $(n-1)$ by $n$.

If the number of $1$s is $i$, the number of $\frac12$s is $h$ and the number of $0$s is $z$ then you have the number of terms, sums of terms, and sums of squares of terms giving
$$n = i + h + z$$ 
$$s = i + h/2$$ 
$$(n-1)d^2 + sm = i + h/4$$

and solving these three simultaneous equations gives

$$i = 2(n-1)d^2 + 2sm - s$$
$$h = 4s - 4(n-1)d^2 - 4sm$$
$$z = n + 2(n-1)d^2 + 2sm - 3s.$$

In you example of $0,0.5,0.5,1,1,1,0,0$ this will have $m=0.5$, $d=0.462910$, $s=4$ leading to $n=8$, $i=3$, $h=2$, $z=3$, perhaps with minor rounding such as reading $2.99999$ as $3$.